# Problems starting a .NET Windows Service when using Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I have created a .NET Windows Service and installed the debug release from the bin/debug folder (yes I know this isn't a good approach, but I just want to be able to test it and attach debugger).

The service basically runs in an endless loop checking an FTP directory for files, processing them, sleeping for a minute and then looping.

When I attempt to start the service I get the following error

```
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
```

On further inspection the service is completing the first loop and then timing out during the first thread sleep. As such I'm somewhat confused as to how I should start the service. Is it my (lack of) understanding of threading that is causing this?

My start code is

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Service started");
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(ProcessFiles);
        workerThread = new Thread(ts);
        workerThread.Start();
    }
```

In the ProcessFiles function, once a loop has been completed I simply have

```
eventLog.WriteEntry("ProcessFiles Loop complete");
Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0,1,0));
```

When I check the event logs the 'ProcessFiles Loop complete' log is there, but that is the last event before the service timesout and fails to start.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

## EDIT

The way I am handling the loop in my ProcessFiles function is as below

```
while (!this.serviceStopped)
{
    // Do Stuff
    eventLog.WriteEntry("ProcessFiles Loop complete");
    Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0,1,0));
}
```

Cheers

Stewart

Comment: can you post more of your code? so far it seems correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I check the event logs the 'ProcessFiles Loop complete' log is there...

You might be having a code for file processing that does not return until the service gets timeout. You are trying to perform some task after interval, you better use [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) or [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) instead of loop to repeatedly perform some task.

*To test if it is loop problem to can restrict loop to single iteration with sleep statement and check if service gets started.*

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 60000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    aTimer.Enabled = false;
    // Put file processing code here.
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I removed the loop and even removed the timeout, but the same error occurs. Ill try your approach over using a worker thread

Comment: How much time the code for file processing taking? As you have to do the file processing after an interval, I would use timer for that.

Comment: See my answer. Schoolboy error! Your comments on handling the intervals were useful though

Answer (score 2):

Doh. I just realised I had the following code in my Main Program method that I was using to be able to debug in VS. Obviously then when I installed the debug release it was putting an infinite timeout on the main thread. Removing the debug code fixed the issue.

```
#if DEBUG
            AdvanceLinkService myService = new AdvanceLinkService();
            myService.OnDebug();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        #else
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new AdvanceLinkService() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun); 
        #endif
```